# Problema com Sintaxe IF Shell Script

Tags: shell, scripting

Tenho o código abaixo:

```
RESPOSTA=$(asterisk -rx "sip show peers" |grep 4003 |awk -F" " '{print $6}')
if[["$RESPOSTA" == "OK"]];then
 echo $RESPOSTA
elif[["$RESPOSTA" == "Unmonitored"]];then
 if[["$RESPOSTA" == "(Unspecified)"]]; then
  cp /dados/automatico.call /var/spool/asterisk/outgoing/
  asterisk -rx reload
 fi
 echo $RESPOSTA
fi
```

porem ele está gerando este erro:

> /dados/status.sh: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `then'
>   /dados/status.sh: line 5:`if[["$RESPOSTA" == "OK"]];then'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O seu script corrigido:

```
RESPOSTA=$(asterisk -rx "sip show peers" |grep 4003 |awk -F" " '{print $6}')
if [[ "$RESPOSTA" = "OK" ]]; then
 echo "$RESPOSTA"
elif [[ "$RESPOSTA" == "Unmonitored" ]]; then
 if [[ "$RESPOSTA" == "(Unspecified)" ]]; then
  cp /dados/automatico.call /var/spool/asterisk/outgoing/
  asterisk -rx reload
 fi
 echo "$RESPOSTA"
fi
```

Faltava-lhe colocar um espaço antes e depois do `[[` e `]]`.

Nota: Para analisar problemas de sintaxe online utilize esta [ferramenta](http://www.shellcheck.net/).

Answer (score 2):

Shell é uma linguagem de programação esquisita. Tecnicamente, o `[[` não é um elemento desintaxe, mas na verdade é um comando que precisa ser separado de seus argumentos usando espaços. Tente reescrever seus ifs nesse formato:

```
if [[ "$RESPOSTA" == "OK" ]]; then
```